# Rsyslog filter option

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I configured my system to put syslog to a remote machine. The logging is heavy and I am running out of memory. so I want to filter it based on priority for example log only error message. I see some of the option in rsyslog website

```
.=info;.=notice;\ mail.none /var/log/messages
```

But this filter criteria does not apply to remote machine only local machine is getting affected. Please let me know how to filter for remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a syntax that allows you to easily filter the log transfer. The filter is placed on the local0 facility :

```
local0.* @@(o)10.0.0.1:514
```

You can also consider a filter on priority that transfer from priority specified to the highest priority :

```
*.error @@(o)10.0.0.1:514
```

will forward logs with priority error, critical, alert and emergency

And finaly, you can combine :

```
local0.*;*.error @@(o)10.0.0.1:514
```

** It's possbile to use conditional structures as explained here.: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html